# How does gravitation work?

Tags: newtonian-gravity

Why the formula is this $$F=G\frac{m_1m_2}{d^2}$$

Why masses are multiplied and devided by d square?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! What are your thoughts? Please note that you are expected to have thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question. And it's important to detail where you're stuck and why, in order to attract good answers. You can consider checking the [advice on writing good questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows [insufficient prior research](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5778). Can you edit your question to mention some things you're already familiar with or things you've found while reading about this topic?

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Please don't post formulas as pictures or plain text, but use MathJax instead. MathJax is easy for people on all devices to read, and can show up clearer on different screen sizes and resolutions. I've edited it here as an example. Look at [this Math SE meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) for a quick tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

d squared is the distance between the gravitating masses. this is a geometrical factor that accounts for the fact that the space through which the field is propagating is three-dimensional, which means that if you double the distance between them, the field strength is diluted by a factor of four.

m1 and m2 are the two masses that are attracting each other. you multiply them together to get the total effect because if you imagine dividing up each mass into tiny pieces, any one tiny piece on one mass is attracting every one of all the many tiny pieces in the other mass. To mathematically account for this correctly, you multiply the masses together instead of, say, just adding them.